# Django exact match of ForeignKey Values

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Sentence(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Tokens(Model):
   token = CharField()
   sentence = ForeignKey(Sentence, related_name='tokens')
```

1. I want to implement two cases: Sentence consists exactly of three
   tokens `['I', 'like', 'apples']`. So list of `sentence.tokens.all()`
   is exactly `['I', 'like', 'apples']`.
2. Same as above, but contains tokens (part of sentence).

`Sentence.objects.annotate(n=Count('tokens',distinct=True)).filter(n=3).filter(tokens__name='I').filter(tokens__name='like').filter(tokens__name='apples')` doesn't work, since it matches `I I I` as well.

Is there any way to filter on exact set of values in ForeignKey?

Comment: have you tried using `__exact`?

Comment: `tokens__name__exact` and `tokens__name__exact` are same.

Comment: I believe that what you want to do is .filter(tokens__name__in=['I', 'like', 'apples']).

Comment: Doesn't seem right to be getting `I I I` back in the result test. Since `I I I` doesn't contain `like` or `apple` it should have been filtered out by one of your last two filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I understand the question better now. Just leveraging elements of your and Jay's code, the following might be one approach. May be not very elegant. But seems to work.

```
def get_sentences(my_tokens):
    counts = dict()
    for t in my_tokens:
        counts[t] = my_tokens.count(t)
    results = Sentence.objects
    for k, v in counts.iteritems():
        results = results.filter(tokens__token=k).annotate(n=Count('tokens',distinct=True)).filter(n__gte=v)
    return results

>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> from my.models import Sentence, Tokens

>>> s1 = Sentence.objects.create(name="S1")
>>> t10 = Tokens.objects.create(token="I", sentence=s1)
>>> t20 = Tokens.objects.create(token="like", sentence=s1)
>>> t30 = Tokens.objects.create(token="apples", sentence=s1)

>>> s2 = Sentence.objects.create(name="S2")
>>> t11 = Tokens.objects.create(token="I", sentence=s2)
>>> t21 = Tokens.objects.create(token="like", sentence=s2)
>>> t31 = Tokens.objects.create(token="oranges", sentence=s2)

>>> s3 = Sentence.objects.create(name="S3")
>>> t31 = Tokens.objects.create(token="I", sentence=s3)
>>> t32 = Tokens.objects.create(token="I", sentence=s3)
>>> t33 = Tokens.objects.create(token="I", sentence=s3)

>>> my_toks = ("I", "like", "apples")
>>> sentences = get_sentences(my_toks)
>>> sentences[0].name
u'S1'

>>> my_toks = ("I", "I", "I")
>>> sentences = get_sentences(my_toks)
>>> sentences[0].name
u'S3'
```

For exact reference, my models look like this:

```
class Sentence(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Tokens(Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    sentence = models.ForeignKey(Sentence, related_name='tokens')
```

Comment: Try to run it with search_tokens = ('I', 'I', 'I'). It will give same results.

Comment: What is if toks_count == len(my_tokens): break for?

Comment: counts = {"I": 3, "I": 3, "I": 3} is impossible since keys should be unique.

Comment: :facepalm: for me! Yes, the break logic is unnecessary. Corrected. Thanks! Also will remove my comment to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get every sentence that contains each of the search tokens?

A flexible (although likely non-optimal) way of doing this might be:

```
search_tokens = ('I', 'like', 'apples')
results = Sentence.objects

for token in search_tokens:
    results = results.filter(tokens__name=token)

results.distinct()
```

This is equivalent to just chaining the filters together:

```
results = Sentence.objects.filter(tokens__name='I').filter(tokens__name='like').filter(tokens__name='apples').distinct()
```

Comment: Try to run it with search_tokens = ('I', 'I', 'I'). It will give same results.

Comment: You want it to match only if all three tokens are present in each sentence? Likely easier to do outside of the DB if that is the case. Just cycle through the sentences and select matches.