# Django filtering queries with Q

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I have confusing problem in querying in django. I know its not a bug and it is something that I don't know.

So models are:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='attribute_values', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have one product object called **T-shirt** and it has two `AttributeValue` with ids 1, 2.
And when I filter like this (1):

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[1, 2]))
```

Its returning my **T-shirt** object. But when I filter like this (2)

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[1]) & Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[2]))
```

there is no queryset found here. How is this happening? Previous codes are just examples and  I have project that really need to do with this second filter (2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will **never** return any query results:

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[1]) & Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[2]))

# Equivalent to:
Product.objects.filter(attribute_values__pk=1).filter(attribute_values__pk=2)
```

Why? Because there is no object that simultaneously possesses both a primary key of `1` AND a primary key of `2`.

You want the `Q` objects to be "OR"ed together instead of "AND"ed, so this is what you actually want:

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[1]) | Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[2]))
```

But why use `Q` objects when you can achieve the same without them? For instance:

```
Product.objects.filter(attribute_values__pk__in=[1, 2])
```

Comment: But I want "AND"ed in my current project case

Comment: @kyore I think I now understand what you want. See if this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238999/django-exact-match-of-foreignkey-values

Answer (score 0):

In this

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[1]), Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[2]))
```

your are using Q expression with and which will not setisfy what you want so for expected output either:

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[1, 2]))
```

or

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[1]) | Q(attribute_values__pk__in=[2]))
```

but you should use the first one without Q expression